# Xstream - Remove value tag

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I've got the following xsd tag:

```
<xs:complexType name="documentation">
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="language" use="required"/>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
```

this generates (with jax-b):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "documentation", propOrder = {
"value"
})
public class Documentation {

  @XmlValue
  protected String value;
  @XmlAttribute(name = "language", required = true)
  protected String language;
```

And I want some output like:

```
<documentation language="NL">SomeValue</documentation>
```

but Xstream generates:

```
<documentation language="NL">
  <value>SomeValue</value>
</documentation>
```

how could I remove the value tags? I don't want them..

Code to generate the xml tags (this is just a snippet..):

```
private void createDocumentation(Description description, String docNL) {
    List<Documentation> documentations = description.getDocumentation();
    Documentation documentationNL = new Documentation();
    documentationNL.setLanguage("NL");
    documentationNL.setValue(docNL);
    documentations.add(documentationNL);
}

private void createXmlFile(Description description) {

    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    xstream.alias("description", Description.class);
    xstream.alias("documentation", Documentation.class);

    xstream.addImplicitCollection(Description.class, "documentation");  
    xstream.useAttributeFor(Documentation.class, "language");

    String xml = xstream.toXML(description);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a custom converter for your Documentation object.

Take a look at the [XStream Converter tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io//converter-tutorial.html)

EDIT TS:

adding:

```
        xstream.registerConverter(new DocumentationConverter());
```

and

```
public class DocumentationConverter implements Converter {

public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
    return clazz.equals(Documentation.class);
}

public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
        MarshallingContext context) {
    Documentation documentation = (Documentation) value;
    writer.addAttribute("language", documentation.getLanguage());
    writer.setValue(documentation.getValue());
}

public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
        UnmarshallingContext context) {
    Documentation documentation = new Documentation();
    reader.moveDown();
    documentation.setLanguage(reader.getAttribute("language"));
    documentation.setValue(reader.getValue());
    reader.moveUp();
    return documentation;
}

}
```

did the job

Answer (score 1):

XStream provides a standard converter implementation called [`ToAttributedValueConverter`](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/extended/ToAttributedValueConverter.html) that you can wire in for any simple-content-plus-attributes type like this:

```
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = { "value" })
public class Documentation {

  protected String value;
  protected String language;
}
```

The `strings` annotation element names the property that corresponds to the element content, all other properties will become attributes.  If you want to declare the converter using `xstream.registerConverter` instead of using XStream annotations then you use

```
xstream.registerConverter(new ToAttributedValueConverter(Documentation.class,
  xstream.getMapper(), xstream.getReflectionProvider(), xstream.getConverterLookup(),
  "value"));
```

(the `Mapper`, `ReflectionProvider` and `ConverterLookup` objects get supplied to the converter automatically when you register it using annotations, but must be provided explicitly for `registerConverter`).

Comment: I can't change the class since it's generated.

Comment: @GregD fair enough, in that case just use the second registration mechanism with `registerConverter`, then there's no need to make any changes to the class.